# update table with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in which the primary key of the first is a foreign key in the second. I want to update the second table, the update can add some rows or delete some rows, how can I implement this using php and mysql.

**post_table**

```
-----------------------            
|   id   |   title    |           
-----------------------
```

**keyword_table**

```
--------------------------------------
|keyword_id |   keyword  |   post_id  |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: i just want to update my keywords

Answer (score 1):

- You can add rows to keyword_table, but post_id must refer to an existing id in post_table.
- You can freely delete rows from keyword_table.
- You cannot delete post_tables lines having dependencies in
  keyword_table, as soon as they would create dependency errors in keyword_table.

  mysqli_query($connection,"insert into keyword_table(keyword_id,keyword,post_id) values(x,y,z)");

It will work as always, you just have to respect the conditions I mentioned earlier.